# which keyword should i use for "Type"

Tags: c#, uwp

In my uwp project i have a List that is called `Rooms` and this is the content in that list:

```
public string RoomID { get; set; }
public string RoomName { get; set; }
public Visibility Projector { get; set; }
public int Seats { get; set; }
public string FrontImage { get; set; }
public string Note { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to insert a value of `Projector` in

```
Rooms.Add(new Room
{
    RoomID = id,
    RoomName = name,
    FrontImage = Img1,
    Seats = seats,
    Note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co"
});
```

With this line of code.

```
Rooms.Insert(1, new Room{ Projector = Visibility.Collapsed });
```

But when i use the keyword `new` a new room is created, is there any other keyword that i can use that insert the "projector" value into my already existing room ?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
foreach (var room in data)
{
    string id = room.id;
    string name = room.name;
    int seats = room.seats;
    List<Roomattribute> roomattrib = room.roomAttributes;
    foreach (var attri in roomattrib)
    {
        int attriId = attri.id;
        string attriName = attri.name;
        int attriIcon = attri.icon;
        if (attriId == 1)
        {
            Rooms.Insert(0, new Room{ Projector = Visibility.Collapsed });
        }  
    }
    Rooms.Add(new Room
    {
        RoomID = id,
        RoomName = name,
        FrontImage = Img1,
        Seats = seats,
        Note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co"
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you have an existing `Room` reference, just use `room.Projector = Visibility.Collapsed;`. How does that interact with you trying to insert a value into a list? Please give more context so we can help you.

Comment: Are you trying to edit the second`Room` in your `Rooms` list? If so, just access it like an array. `Rooms[1].Projector = Visibility.Collapsed`

Comment: @kenny there is still means to do it in c#, yet it often smell bad code

Comment: Check The Edit.

Comment: So if your new room has a Roomattribute with an id of 1, you want to add it to the beginning of the list? Or do you want to edit the first one in the list with the new information? Please add to your question what you're trying to accomplish with your code.

Comment: I want to edit the first one with the new information :) @TJWolschon

Comment: If you're only trying to change `Projector` then my updated answer will work. If you're trying to update all of the fields, then you would either go one-by-one through each of them, or just replace it with the new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
foreach (var room in data)
{
    var newRoom = new Room()
    {
        RoomID = room.id,
        RoomName = room.name,
        FrontImage = Img1,
        Seats = room.seats,
        Note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co"
    };

    //if any of the room's attribute's ID is 1
    if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id == 1))
        newRoom.Projector = Visibility.Collapsed;

    Rooms.Add(newRoom);
}
```

Or even simpler with a single transformation line of code (note the "null" below may need to be adjusted to the default if that's an enum).  This avoids the foreach altogether, and reads very concisely.  It's how I would write this code.

```
Rooms.AddRange(data.Select(a => new Room() {
        RoomID = a.id,
        RoomName = a.name,
        FrontImage = Img1,
        Seats = a.seats,
        Note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co"
        Projector = a.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id == 1) ? Visibility.Collapsed : null
    });
```

Comment: If this is what the OP is trying to achieve, this is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to edit a property of the second room in your list, which is what it looks like because you're using index=1 (remember arrays and lists start at zero), then it's quite simple. EDIT: You've said you want to edit the first one, so the only change that needs to be made is to use 0 as your index.

```
Rooms[0].Projector = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

The above should work if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @luddep let me know if you need further explanation with this problem

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: @luddep definitely check out TheSoftwareJedi's answer as well. If that's the functionality you're looking for it's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @TJWolschon.  Logically, I think that's what he's getting at.  I can't see how a room having some attribute means to go set the first room to have a projector.  I get the feeling he's attempting to operate of the room he's about to create.  Lup: Let us know if either of these solves the issue.  They're both correct - but do different things.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi yeah I questioned myself when I was first writing it, thinking "this surely can't be what he needs, right?".

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Im going to try it out a little bit and come back with the results as soon as posible :)